# cached scheduler task not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

How do I invoked URL get request in the task in the following code example. The url `http://mysite/SMS/SendText` is not getting invoked after 60 seconds.

```
        private static CacheItemRemovedCallback OnCacheRemove = null;

        private void AddTask(string name, int seconds)
        {
            OnCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, seconds, null,
                DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
        }

        public void CacheItemRemoved(string k, object v, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
        {
            // do stuff here if it matches our taskname, like WebRequest
            // re-add our task so it recurs
            AddTask(k, Convert.ToInt32(v));
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {

            AddTask("http://localhost:1901/SMS/SendText", 60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on [Cache.Insert Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y13wyk9.aspx) you must use the `UtcNow`, and not the `Now` function when you add the date expiration.

So "my guess" here is that you have a throw error that you can not direct see, and the Insert is not working because the 60 seconds on Now, convert them to UtcNow have already expired.